# Why JAVA can not compile when using generic type in interface

Tags: java, generics

Hello I have a problem using generic types in java. The actual problem is that when I am using generic type on a method declaration is working fine. Then if I a add a generic type to the interface declaration the code does not compile. Following is the working code:

```
public interface IRuntimeConvert {
    public <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(String o, Class<T> clazz);
}

public class RuntimeConvertImpl implements IRuntimeConvert {

    private final Map<String, Object> hashMap;

    public RuntimeConvertImpl(Map<String, Object> hashMap) {
        this.hashMap = hashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(String o, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            return clazz.cast(hashMap.get(o));
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("s", "string");
    hashMap.put("i", 0);
    hashMap.put("l", 0L);

    IRuntimeConvert rtConvert = new RuntimeConvertImpl(hashMap);

    String s = rtConvert.convertInstanceOfObject("s", String.class);
    System.out.println(s);
    Integer i = rtConvert.convertInstanceOfObject("i", Integer.class);
    System.out.println(i);
    Long l = rtConvert.convertInstanceOfObject("l", Long.class);
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

The above code is compiling. When I made the following changes the code is not compilable.

```
public interface IRuntimeConvert<S> {

    public <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(String o, Class<T> clazz);

    public S getSomething(S s);
}

public class RuntimeConvertImpl implements IRuntimeConvert<Object> {

    private final Map<String, Object> hashMap;

    public RuntimeConvertImpl(Map<String, Object> hashMap) {
        this.hashMap = hashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(String o, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            return clazz.cast(hashMap.get(o));
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSomething(Object s) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }

}
```

After the above changes in the main class I encouted a type cast error for each invocation of the method rtConvert.convertInstanceOfObject("s", String.class) with error message :

```
Incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String.
```

If I try to run the main I get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Comment: Type erasure.  Java generics are not like C++ templates: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Hi cparaskeva - can you edit your question to include more details of how and where it does not compile?

Comment: If you get an error, always include the error message.

Comment: I test your code after removing the ** **, creating two files IRuntimeConvert and RuntimeConvertImpl. adding and import to java.util.Map. And it compiled fine.

Comment: `IRuntimeConvert**<S>**` - this is invalid code, if you think this comments it is not. use `//`

Comment: What java/javac version are you using ? I just compiled it fine with `javac 1.8.0_92`. (after removing the stars of course)

Comment: When I run the main I encounter: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String I have java 1.8.0_91-b14

Comment: Yes, still same issue

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you have specified the generic type in your implementation to be `Object` with the following line:

```
public class RuntimeConvertImpl implements IRuntimeConvert<Object> {
```

As such, a call to `getSomething` will always have to return an `Object`. However, since `String` is a subclass of `Object`, this can not be automatically cast to a `String`, you'd have to do something like:

```
String s = (String) rtConvert.getSomething();
```

Note that this does not guarantee type safety and may lead to `ClassCastException`s.

Comment: If you want to use generics ... use them! If you want a String object to be returned just instanciate it : IRuntimeConvert<String> rtConvert
But as this answer explain the issue, I vote for it

Comment: Thank tou for you explanation! Indeed I had a missundestanding regarding generics.

Comment: As far as I could check, there was no `getSomething()` in the `main()` method. Thus no compile error here.

Comment: Indeed, the OP didn't mention any changes of the code in the `main` method, yet I wanted to exemplify what this usage of generics would lead to. Thus the phrasing "you'd have to" ;)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot code the java language specification for you. I simply draw some conclusions.

If you change one line in `main()` :

```
IRuntimeConvert<?> rtConvert = new RuntimeConvertImpl(hashMap);
//        type ^^^^
```

Then the `main()` will compile. So, apparently, `javac` needs *all* the generics to be defined for the actual object type. Then it can deal with the method-level generic parameters.

Comment: This happens with parallel editing. +1 for you too anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with Java trying to infere generic types. It's solved if you specify the generic type of the `rtConvert` variable in the main method: `IRuntimeConvert<Object> rtConvert`, instead of just `IRuntimeConvert rtConvert`.

By default, I always try to specify the generic types of variables.

Comment: Yes, thank you that was the issue! However i thought that by default Java is replacing unbound types to object